# Retrofit: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 2 column 2 path

Tags: android, retrofit

I have a Json, and Search feature, My problem is :

I got 3 items :
 1. Test 1
 2. Test 2
 3. Test 3

Let's say the user want to search for Test, he submit "Test", All the related Test will be shown .

But, if he wanted only "Test 1", it will throw the error in the title, Sometimes it shows, sometimes no .

What files do you want if needed ?

Error :

```
 com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 2 column 2 path $
```

To mention, when searching for "2", it will show "Test 2", but searching for "Test 2" will throw an error .

It was working on basic Json, after switching to the new library, it stopped working .

Json :

```
{"roms_center":[{"device_name":"Test 1","roms_count":"1","device_id":"0"},{"device_name":"Test 2","roms_count":"2","device_id":"1"}]}
```

Code to parse it :

Interface

```
        @GET("api.php")
    Call<Model> getRoms_center(@Query("company_name") String name);
```

Model :

```
    private class Model{
    private List<CatItem> roms_center;

    public List<CatItem> getRoms_center() {
        return roms_center;
    }

    public void setRoms_center(List<CatItem> roms_center) {
        this.roms_center = roms_center;
    }

}
```

Make Connection method (Library method) :

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Base)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    ReApi Api = retrofit.create(ReApi.class);
Connection = Api.getRoms_center(Company);
Connection.enqueue(new Callback<Model>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Model> call, Response<Model> response) {

            ProgressLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            isLoading = false;

            List<CatItem> ROMs = response.body().getRoms_center();
            for(int i = 0 ; i < ROMs.size() ; i ++ ){
                CatItem Item = new CatItem();

                Item.setDevice_Name(ROMs.get(i).getDevice_Name());
                Item.setTotal_Downloads(ROMs.get(i).getTotal_Downloads());
                Item.setDevice_ID(ROMs.get(i).getDevice_ID());

                if(rowListItem == null)
                    rowListItem = new ArrayList<>();

                rowListItem.add(Item);
            }

            Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

Comment: How about the error logs? That seems useful

Comment: I've edited the op .

Comment: Your JSON parser sees an Array instead of an Object, and so it is throwing that error. Please include both your parsing code and the JSON being parsed

Comment: Edited, Please check .

Comment: Sorry, wrong json, Check again .. the json is correct, just a copy problem :p .

Comment: Why are you making a new CatItem and manually doing `Item.setDevice_Name` for example? Gson should already be making those CatItem objects for you.

Comment: I used to do it in past Json manual parsing, as i said i'm still a noob in this library .

Comment: Well, assuming Gson worked correctly, `ROMs.get(i)` is what you should add to `rowListItem`, but at that point `rowListItem` is the exact same as `ROMs`, so that whole loop is pointless. Regarding the JSON error, I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: I've switched the adding method, Json is valid, Code is valid, when searching for exact name, it won't show it, but if searching for a part of it "2" from "Test", it will show. 
The PHP code is correct, tested on basic JSON parser, plus tried the query on PhpMyAdmin .

Comment: So the string "2" is being sent to some PHP site, which queries MySQL and reads a result into JSON? That's far too many moving pieces to isolate the problem on StackOverflow, I'm afraid. Just for completeness, though, please show the SQL query you are using and maybe the schema of the table

Comment: Seems like the problem is in the space? after adding a space, it will throw the error .

Comment: I don't know what you're looking at, but you are returning an Array instead of an Object like I originally said, so if the space causes the problem, then include **that** JSON in your question

Comment: Solved! it was a space problem, when the query contains " ", it will make it "+", So Test 2 = Test+2, it must be like this : Test 2.
I didn't need to add it, but seems something wrong with it .

Comment: Right, you'll need to URL decode on the PHP side. That, however is a question in itself that should be asked with the php tag.

Comment: Solved by replacing "+" with " " in java side, this problem shouldn't happen at all, in basic Json parser didn't happen .

Comment: Read this link : https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/02/recyclerview-json-parsing.html

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your interface:

```
 @GET("api.php")
Call<List<Model>> getRoms_center(@Query("company_name") String name);
```